# Замена текста

Tags: php

Здравствуйте.

Объясню на примере. У нас есть такой текст:

```
    <p>Привет.</p>
    <p>.</p>
    <p>У нас Вы можете приобрести телефон iPhone.</p>
    <p>.</p><p>.</p>
    <p>Скидки:</p>
    <p>.</p>
<p>.</p>
<p>.</p>
    <p>При покупке 2-х и более - скидка 5%.</p>
```

Нужно сделать из этого текста такой вариант:

```
  <p>Привет.</p>
    <p>.</p>
    <p>У нас Вы можете приобрести телефон iPhone.</p>
    <p>.</p>
    <p>Скидки:</p>
    <p>.</p>
    <p>При покупке 2-х и более - скидка 5%.</p>
```

Т.е. если `<p>.</p>` повторяется более 1 раза подряд (подряд - возможные разделители: пробел, перенос строки), то скрипт оставляет только 1 `<p>.</p>`.

Как такое сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$str = preg_replace("#(<p>.</p>\s*)+#", "<p>.</p>\n", $str);
```